# Why no_new_privs bit is required with seccomp? example of theoretical exploit

Tags: privileges, exploit, seccomp

I've seen that before using seccomp mode filter you have to set this bit, because it guarantees that a child process can't be executed with greater privileges compared to the parent's ones. But still I can't figure out an exploitation example. Could you show me one?

**THEORETICAL SCENARIO:** I have a program which can set seccomp filter mode without set no_new_privs bit.

**GOAL:** show a program which exploits it

> This requirement ensures that an
>                     unprivileged process cannot apply a malicious filter and then
>                     invoke a set-user-ID or other privileged program using
>                     execve(2), thus potentially compromising that program.  (Such
>                     a malicious filter might, for example, cause an attempt to use
>                     setuid(2) to set the caller's user IDs to nonzero values to
>                     instead return 0 without actually making the system call.
>                     Thus, the program might be tricked into retaining superuser
>                     privileges in circumstances where it is possible to influence
>                     it to do dangerous things because it did not actually drop
>                     privileges.)

Comment: Doesn't the quoted text give you an example situation?

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/562260/211239) is the exact answer you want.